# why isn't return <Redirect to="/" /> running?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

How come the return  is not running?  Is it because it is nested in 2 if statement?
I am trying to do in in React, where I am checking the custom claims from Firebase, and if the user is an admin, then it will be redirected to the admin home page.  Thanks~!

```
export default function() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);


    if (currentUser != null) {
      currentUser.getIdTokenResult().then(idTokenResult => {
        if (idTokenResult.claims.adminRole) {
          return <Redirect to="/adminHome" />;
        }
      });
    }

   return ( ... )
}
```

Comment: any error msg ?

Comment: no error, it just doesnt redirect to the /adminHome,  but if I put the "return <Redirect ..> only in the first if statement, then it will run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<Redirect to="/adminHome" />` can work, but not in your case. Because `getIdTokenResult`is async operation, and the `return` in the end of your component will return the result before the async `getIdTokenResult` operation will be finished. And when `getIdTokenResult` will complete, it's too late to return something.

To do a redirect, do next:

1. import history

   import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
2. Use hook in component

   const history = useHistory()

And replace your code:

```
return <Redirect to="/adminHome" />;
```

to next:

```
history.push('/adminHome')
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!  Is it because I am using hooks so I should be using history.push() rather than <Redirect />

Comment: I've added an explanation in my answer. I hope now it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

currently, your condition is not passing through. Just modify an `if` statement.

```
if (idTokenResult.claims && idTokenResult.claims.adminRole) {
          return <Redirect to="/adminHome" />;
 }
```

If `idTokenResult.claims.adminRole` exists in an initial render the you can also try `this.props.history.push("/adminHome") return null;`.

Comment: the conditions does pass through, if I put a console.log("test") in the nested if statement, it does print "test", but the return statement does not redirect me, I also tried your solution, but the idTokenResult is a promise, so I cannot use 1 if statement, it will say the idTokenResult is not defined, thanks

Comment: Okay.That's interesting. Can you just try with `this.props.history.push('/adminHome')` else remove return.

Comment: Thanks CodeZombie!  I actually tried your way with the history.push() before the other answer, so technically your answer is right! But I am not using props so the other answer's syntax is more accurate, thank you so much for your help though!

Comment: No problem @L.A.